# getElementById in separate js file doesn't find ASP.net control

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

When I have this in the page markup it works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function bought1()
    {
        var s = '<%= Button2.ClientID %>';
        var v = document.getElementById(s);
        v.click();
    }    
</script>
```

But when I have the same thing in a separate file, even though the function *is* executed - the value of `v` remains `null`.

I tried with a simple `div` and it *did* find the `div`.

Why doesn't it find the ASP.net Button?

EDIT

I even added `ClientIDMode="Static"` to the Button. No change.

Comment: You checked the actual rendered html on both pages?

Comment: @Darren I checked with IE and FF js debuggers - they both give a `null` for `v`.

Comment: An immediate "fix" would be to give it a class and target that class. When put in a separate JS file, the `<%= Button2.ClientID %>` does **not** get evaluated because JavaScript files are not evaluated by the ASP.NET server - they are served statically.

Comment: @ispiro - i mean view the actual source. See what gets rendered for `var s = '<%= Button2.ClientID %>';` etc...

Comment: also, as @ian says - the server tags `<% %>` won't work in a separate .js file.

Comment: @Darren It only shows `<script type='text/javascript' src='JScript1.js'></script>`.

Comment: @ispiro If you use `ClientIDMode="Static"`, then change your code to: `var s = 'Button2';` (and make sure you clear your browser's cache and reload the page)

Comment: @Ian I did change it to `'<%= Button2 %>'`. But from Win's answer, assuming it's correct, I see that that won't help. (`Button2` will of course.) Thanks.

Comment: @ian - he meant change it to `var s = 'Button2';` and not `var s = '<%= Button2 %>';` - do this after putting `ClientIDMode="Static"` on your button

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<%= Button2.ClientID %>` is a server code. You cannot run server code in a separate  javascript file.

If you want to access Server Control ID from separate javascript, you need to make the `ClientIDMode` to either preditable or static.

[Here is an example.](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2010/May/04/Whats-New-in-ASPNET-40-Part-Two-WebForms-and-Visual-Studio-Enhancements)

The following is a code. It is not a good example, but I hope you get the idea.

*Note: Make sure you do not have same Ids when you use `ClientIDMode="Static"`. Otherwise, Ids will collide. For example, one in master page and one in content page.*

### ASPX

```
<script src="/JavaScript1.js"></script>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" ClientIDMode="Static" 
    Text="I am a button" />
<div onclick="bought1()">Click Me</div>
```

### Javascript File

```
function bought1() {
    var s = 'Button1';
    var v = document.getElementById(s);
    v.click();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Win is correct, your separate JS file will not be rendered by ASP.net.

However, if you simply put

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var s = '<%= Button2.ClientID %>';
</script>
```

above where you load your external file, you will load the value into a global on the page that will be accessible from any scripts loaded after it. Just make sure to give it a name that wont collide with any libraries you have loaded.

Comment: That's exactly what the `ClientID ` is for (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1119035/939213).) And besides - it _does_ work in the first case.

Comment: Ah, misunderstood question. Updated!

Comment: You mean that I'll be able to use `s` in the external file? That looks like a good solution. Thanks.

Comment: @ispiro Yeah, since it's declared globally, you can access it from any scope in JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

You should Change the function like this:

```
function bought1(clientId)
{
    var s = clientId;
    var v = document.getElementById(s);
    v.click();
}
```

and would call it in your page markup:

```
bought1('<%= Button2.ClientID %>')
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you want to avoid the messiness of JS globals and dumping asp.net variables altogether, just wrap your button and use a queryselector (or jquery, etc) to grab it:

asp.net:

```
<div id="button-container">
        <asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function bought1()
    {
        var v = document.querySelector("#button-container input");
        v.click();
    }    
</script>
```

Comment: Or `document.getElementById("button-container").children[0]`. Good idea though :)

Comment: I mostly just like document.querySelector, heh. Also i couldn't remember if .net added any other markup around the button, but thankfully it doesn't.

Comment: Oh I do too, I just thought for this very specific example, my example would work too, and have "better" browser support. Yeah, luckily for a button, it doesn't add extra markup, but would ruin my solution if it did.

Comment: Yep, getElementById is definitely the way to go for anybody targeting a wide audience.